# Tkinter Function Placement

Tags: python, tkinter

Ignoring the indentation being wrong, how can I get this function to work? It currently throws up an error saying it asks for 0 positional arguments and gets one.

```
class BMR(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    var1 = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Male", bg='white', variable=var1).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='S')
    var2 = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Female", bg='white', variable=var1).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='S')

    tk.Button(self, text="Submit!", width=6, command=self.gender).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

def gender():
    if var1.get() and var2.get():
        print('Please only tick one box')
        var1.set(0)
        var2.set(0)
    elif var1.get():
        print('Male')
    elif var2.get():
        print('Female')
    else:
        print('Please tick male or female')

app = theog()
app.mainloop()
```

When I tick a checkbox and hit calculate I get the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: gender() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: **def gender(self):**

Comment: Why should we ignore the indentation? Indentation is critical in python. When it is incorrect, we have a hard time guessing what it's supposed to be. Is `gender` a method inside `BMR`? Is it a private function inside `__init__`? Is it a standalone function out side of either of those? Please fix the indentation. Also, please show the full and exact error message.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my way to work and wanted to post it before I left. I have fixed it as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Define your function inside of the class and call it like any other class function. Self.func.

Comment: Its called a class method not a class function. You can have normal functions inside of a class and call them without the use of `self.`.